# Android connect to oracle database

Tags: android, database, oracle

Hi i'm having a problem connecting to an oracle database. When I launch my application in emulator it works just fine. But when I try to run it on my phone it crashes. I get the following error:

> detailMessage  "Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

My connectivity code is:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection conn;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port/dtabase name","user", "port");
```

So any ideas on what could be a problem? I have the data connection turned on on my phone...

Comment: is the database uploaded on your device?

Comment: I think this is a firewall issue on your DB server...

Comment: How could firewall allow my emulator to connect and not phone?

Comment: Hello @gabrjan may I know what tutorials you are using for this? Please give me a link to it, because I want to try to connect my android app to oracle.

Comment: I finished up in writting an apy for it, and i don't realy remember how was i doing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that either you have not requested internet permissions in your manifest or you are using a local IP and your device is trying to connect over WAN and not LAN.

Comment: i use ip as in 190.160.111.14 nad in my manifest i have   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: And have you opened up that port and verified that it is accessible? Surely there is more to the error message. Can you dump the full stack trace.

Comment: Hmm should i open port on my phone or what?

Comment: As indicated in the other comment, a firewall or router may be blocking the port. If your database is being run on your development machine for instance, to access your development machine database from a WAN device such as your phone, you need to open the port on your router so external devices can access the database. This is typically called port forwarding in the router settings.

Comment: Ok i solved the problem, the database is being run on remote machine but on my development comp i have checkpoint endpoint runing... i know i'm idiot :S Any ideas how to open that port?

Comment: You would have to open the port on the remote machine to be accessible. Being a database this would be highly unusual as its essentially against common practice to open your database to the WAN directly. The most common practice imo would be to write an API that only provides access to the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting mobile devices directly to an RDBMS is not recommended. It is technically possible, but there are serious security implications, not to mention performance, battery life, etc.

Oracle actually offers a product specifically designed for connecting mobile devices to and Oracle backend: Oracle Database Mobile Server.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/database-mobile-server/overview/index.html

You can read about it there, also download and try it out from the download tab. In addition to Oracle Database, you'll need an app server. WebLogic or Glassfish are recommended.

It offers several advantages, the main one being the ability to synchronize SQLite data from Android devices with an Oracle backend without any additional development effort. You get the ability for the app to function in disconnected mode, and it offers some basic device mgmt capability.

Good luck with your project.

Eric Jensen, Oracle PM